# trouble styling li and span - margin / padding / positioning

Tags: html, css, position, margin, padding

I have my theme's pagination links set in a `div` within a `div`. Ideally, the pagination link `div` should be centered both vertically and horizontally, and the `li` elements should align horizontally with the `span` elements. My problem is, none of those elements will budge regardless of what I do. I'm a little confused, and certain I'm overlooking something.. just not sure what it is.

[live site](http://blog.christaandivy.com/)

```
<div class="pagination">    
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_post_link('<span class="left-arrow"></span>&nbsp;OLDER POSTS'); ?></li>
            <li><?php next_post_link('NEWER POSTS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="right-arrow"></span>'); ?></li>
        </ul>            
    </div><!-- end pagination -->

#blog .pagination {
    background: url('img/dots_large.png') no-repeat;
    height: 169px;
    width: 635px;
    margin-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 2;
}

#blog .pagination ul { 
    background: #fff;
    display:inline;
    padding: 15px;
}

#blog .pagination ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#blog .pagination .left-arrow {
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#blog .pagination .right-arrow {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#blog .pagination span.left-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
}

#blog .pagination span.right-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: FIRST thing: add a doctype. Everything else is a waste of time till you haven't done that

Comment: @FelipeAls of course my full site code has doctype, I just grabbed the relevant snippet as an example. I'll remember to add doctype in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change these

```
#blog .pagination ul { 
    background: #fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#blog .pagination ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

that should do it

Comment: That solved my problem of positioning the `div` as a whole within the larger `div`, thank you.

The other problem listed was aligning the `li` and `span` elements. Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: Ultimately, I combined your code for `ul` and `ul li` with the other answers bits regarding the `span` to successfully achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @AMC I'm not understanding what you want - did you figure it out?

Comment: I did; ended up combining elements from yours and the other answer to solve my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
#blog .pagination ul {
    background: #FFF;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

#blog .pagination ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}

#blog .pagination span.right-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_right.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

#blog .pagination span.left-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_left.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

As noted, though, you MUST include a doctype at the top of your pages. E.g. add this to the very top of your templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: To reiterate what I stated above, my full site code has doctype, I just grabbed the relevant snippet as an example. I'll remember to add doctype in the future. Thank you.

Thank you.
Ultimately, I combined your code regarding the `span` with the other answer's bits for `ul` and `ul li` to successfully achieve the desired effect.