# Unable to space LI elements

Tags: html, css

Can't get padding, margin, or line-spacing to work on any UL/LI/ or A tags in CSS.

Keep in mind, I have a CSS reset stylesheet setup before loading all other style sheets.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="h_logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x125/000/fff"></div>
<div class="h_navbar">
                        <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                                    <a href="#"><li>Web Design</li></a>
                                    <a href="#"><li>Advertising</li></a>
                                    <a href="#"><li>Publishing</li></a>
                                </ul>
                        </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.h_logo{
width:800px;
height:125px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
clear:both;
}
.h_nabar{
width:1000px;
height:125px;
padding:10px;
}
.h_navbar li{
list-style-type:none;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:100px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;

}
.h_navbar ul{
display:table;
margin:auto;
}
.h_navbar a{
text-decoration:none;
display:table-cell;
border:2px double black;
font-size:18px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NcgA3/)

Comment: You can't wrap `<li>` elements in `<a>`.

Comment: This site will notify you of the errors in your html and css: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Ok so that solved the issue. But if I add width for the LI elements to make them larger, it spaces uneven with the other tabs. Like some have more space between each other than the other. http://jsfiddle.net/NcgA3/2/

Comment: @user3582182 it doesn't have uneven spaces, you just put the `border` in the wrong element, you should switch your `border` to `li` from `a`

Comment: possible duplicate of [trouble styling li and span - margin / padding / positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950675/trouble-styling-li-and-span-margin-padding-positioning)

Comment: I can assure you @dcc this is not a duplicate....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS

```
.h_logo{
    width:800px;
    height:125px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.h_nabar{
    width:1000px;
    height:125px;
    padding:10px;
}

.h_navbar li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:120px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #111;
}
.h_navbar ul{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
.h_navbar a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:15px;/*Adjust your margin here*/
    width:120px;
    height:50px;
}
```

### HTML

[image]

- Home
- Web Design
- Advertising
- Publishing